# Hibernate query for perfomance

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table looking something like this;

```
@Table
public class Person {

  private String name;
  private String address;
  ...
  private String score;
}
```

In my database I now have a lot of persons with names, addresses and scores. Lets say I retrieve a list of persons from another system, where some of the persons already exist in the database and some are new.

Before I persist them in my DB I want to check if they already exist (avoid duplicates), and maybe change the score if the person I get in is the same as the one I already have, but with a different score.

Whats the best query to write if I want to select all persons that exist? (eg. same name and address). My table of persons can contain a huge amount of persons and the list of persons I get in from the other system is also big (new or with updated scores). I need a query that is all about performance :-).

I am using Java and Hibernate. Anyone?

EDIT: The final sql will probably look something like

```
select * from Person where name='Paul' AND address='road1 
OR name='John' AND address='road2'
OR name='Stella' AND address='road3'
```

and many many more.. The above sql atleast explains what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to outer join both tables and list all the persons that don't exist on a side . like this (TSQL):

```
SELECT left.* from db1.owner.persons left LEFT JOIN db2.owner.persons right ON left.name=right.name AND left.address=right.address WHERE right.id IS NULL
```

Then you can use CreateSQLQuery method of ISession to get the list of persons.

in C# we write it like this

```
var list=session.CreateSQLQuery(queryString,"left",new []{typeof(Person)}).List();
```

but I don't think that's much different in java

If you want to gain performance over this query probably it's necessary to put some indexes on each table (over name and address for example)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. It's not two tables, just one. Basically I get a "List<Person> persons". I just want to compare the persons in the list I get with the ones in my db.

Comment: I thought you want to implement a logic for getting new users from another system

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you already have all your "external" persons in memory.

I would create a `Map<String, ExternalPerson>` containing all your external persons indexed by name.

I would then ask the `keySet()` of this map to get the list of persons to get from the database.

I would then execute the following query:

```
select p from Person p where p.name in (:names)
```

You just has to make sure that the number of names isn't above the limit imposed by your database (1000 in Oracle). If so, you'll have to split the set into several subsets, and repeat the query for each subset.

Then iterate over the query results. For each person found, get its corresponding external person using the map or external persons, and update the score of the current person. Then remove the external person from the map.

At the end of the process, the map contains the external persons that don't exist in the database, and must be created.

If the set of persons is really hign, make sure to use `query.scroll()` rather than `query.list()` to iterate through the persons, and regularly flush and clear the session as explained in [this section of the reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-inserts), to avoid memory problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! We are closing in, but one thing I am wondering about; This would be great answer if I only could index by name, but I also have to index by address. (Stupid example I gave, but its not really a table of persons :-)). If the persons name AND address is equal, then I want that person. If I expand to select p from Person p where p.name in (:names) and p.address in (:address) will that work? (Neither name or address is unique (or primary key) in this table) My first guess is no....?

Comment: I think you'll have to compose your query dynamically, then. Consider using a criteria query with a loop to generate your disjunction. I think HQL supports the syntax where `(a, b) in (('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', 'blam'))`, but I don't know if it's possible to bind a collection of tuples `<name, address>` to such a query.